# How to tie two HTML radio options to a input type file?

Tags: php, html

Using PHP

I want to have a user select a radio option:  yes / no  when they attach a file to **input type=file**

I add file inputs along with the radios to the end of my form dynamically with JS. I need to store the file along with the yes / no in the resulting post. I can upload & store the file fine.

But, how can I tie the yes / no radio to the file when there could be many files being uploaded at once.  $_FILES array has the file input and $_POST array has the radio boxes but how can I tie them together to know that this yes/no response goes with this file etc.?

This is different than my other question in that the other question had a checkbox, this has radio buttons. And the other question did not actually answer the original problem at hand!

[image]

Comment: So, there are two radios (yes/no) for every file?

Comment: Then you can use indexes. For example radios yes/no for first file will have name `name="radio0"` and in PHP you will use: `$_POST['radio0']` for `$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][0]` as example.

Comment: Re edit: The answer to your other question did solve the problem at hand. While there are differences between radio buttons and checkboxes, the only ones that matter for this problem are ones that require additional work for *checkboxes* so you can reuse the solution for radio buttons without any trouble.

Comment: @debute this is along the lines of what I want to do, but the users have the option to delete an attachment before saving. 
If they delete a couple before saving then they might submit radio2 & radio3 but that won't match up to $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][2] & [3] because there would only be $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][0] & [1]